# Design Model for multiple sources (XML/JSON)

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, model-view-controller, design-patterns

Let's say I have my application which receives login information (or credentials) from different sources. Now the input source can be in different formats (XML/JSON, etc)

How do I handle these multiple input sources such that I am finally able to authenticate the user in my application and accordingly show him the homepage ?

I am asking in terms of Design pattern or approach to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uhm, convert all the input in a canonical form and go from there. I think you should give samples of the input you receive in order to get a better answer.

Comment: I am looking at handling mainly from JavaScript perspective (with some Java help)...like say I get XML input from one source and JSON input from some other source...now how do I handle these different sources and process furher...

Comment: I had thought of using Adapter pattern and design an interface which would accept different input sources and finally return one common output format like JSON...I am not sure if that is the correct way though...

Comment: Yes. Transform everything you get into a canonical form.

Comment: Could you please add more details as to what u mean by canonical form

Comment: What I mean by `canonical` is a unique way to represent the data.